# Match a Path Vlookup

Tags: excel

I have tow table which looks like this:
**Table B:**

```
+-----------+--------------------+----------+
| DocNumber |        URL         |   Type   |
+-----------+--------------------+----------+
| HTZ12     | http://google.com  | URL      |
| HT45      | www.halloworld.com | Car      |
| ZT1245    | Test               | Building |
+-----------+--------------------+----------+
```

**Table A:**

```
+-----------+------------------+
| DocNumber |       URL        |  
+-----------+------------------+
| HTZ12     | http://google.   |  
| HT45      | www.halloworld.c |  
| ZT1245    | Test             |  
+-----------+------------------+
```

Both tables are in the same excel sheet I would like to do a vlookup from tabel A to B via the DocNuber and get the Type from Tabel B

```
=VLOOKUP(J2;Old_Internal_library!A:L;1;0)
```

in J2 is the DocNumber from Tabel A

That is image of tabel A (going via Document Number **J**)

[image: Tabel A]

Table B where I want to get the Turbocharger Type in column **D**
[image]

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You want to do a VLOOKUP matching the DocNumber? Is Old_Internal_library Table B? I've never used semicolons in my formulae, is that your issue rather than commas?

Comment: @TimEdwards  want to get the Type from Table B to Table A via a VLOOKUP and my only "constant" is the DocNumber to create a match other wise i could just copy paste it ..

Comment: Jordan has given you the solution based on what I think you want to do. The 3rd argument is the column of your lookup range that you want to return. So you need 3 rather than 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is looking up the data in the leftmost column in your range of `Old_Internal_library!A:L` and returning the data in the first column in the range. The `1` in your formula represents which column (relative to your range) you are returning data from.

So for example, if you are looking up the 'Type', which looks to be in the 3rd column in your range, you will need to change your formula to:

```
=VLOOKUP(J2;Old_Internal_library!A:L;3;0)
```

**EDIT:**

As the lookup value is in `Column E` of Table B and the value you'd like to return is in `Column D` you will need to use an [INDEX/MATCH](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/214142) function. Try:

```
=INDEX(Old_Internal_library!D:D;MATCH(J2;Old_Internal_library!E:E;0))
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for your time and answer ! but I just get back a #N/A which is wrong since I manually check it if there is a match and there is

Comment: The most likely reason for this is that the 'DocNumber' in `J2` does not appear in `Old_Internal_library!A:A`. Which column in your 'Old_Internal_library' worksheet (Table B) are your DocNumbers?

Comment: I already check that out and yes there are some examples in my tabel where it does not match but that was clear to me from the beginning, but there are cases where it 100 % should match

Comment: If the DocNumbers are in `Old_Internal_library!A:A` and aren't matching when you think they should be it might be worth checking for leading and trailing spaces. You can use `TRIM()` to remove any trailing spaces. Formatting of the cells may also result in mismatching. If you are comparing a string of numbers to a number they will not match, e.g. "123456" (text string format) will not match a cell containing 123456 in number format. Check that the values in `Column J` in `Table A` are in the same format as the values in `Column A` of `Table B`.

Comment: [link](https://s11.postimg.io/t6tmujvg3/image.png) here is the image of tabel of tabel A and as you see in Column J is the doc number and here a image of tabel b https://s11.postimg.io/422mh4vzn/image.png here I want to get the Turbocharger Type btw maybe you have to zoom in

Comment: From looking at the images it looks like your 'Document Numbers' are actually in `Column E` in 'Table B' and your 'Turbocharger Type' is in `Column D`. Because the lookup value is after the value you want to return you will need to use an [INDEX/MATCH](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/214142) function. I will update the question now with the formula.

Comment: ohh I did not now that appreciating allot for updating your answer !

Comment: No problem, have you got it working now? If so you can mark the answer as correct to show the issue has been resolved. Have a good day, Thanks.